# Cargo build failed: could not find macro `llvm_asm` in this scope

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to build [rust-fractal-gui](https://github.com/rust-fractal/rust-fractal-gui.git) but the build always fails with these errors:

```
$ cargo build --release

...

Compiling parking_lot v0.11.2
error: cannot find macro `llvm_asm` in this scope
  --> /home/riley/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/parking_lot-0.11.2/src/elision.rs:77:13
   |
77 |             llvm_asm!("xacquire; lock; cmpxchgq $2, $1"
   |             ^^^^^^^^

error: cannot find macro `llvm_asm` in this scope
   --> /home/riley/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/parking_lot-0.11.2/src/elision.rs:108:13
    |
108 |             llvm_asm!("xrelease; lock; xaddq $2, $1"
    |             ^^^^^^^^

error[E0635]: unknown feature `llvm_asm`
  --> /home/riley/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/parking_lot-0.11.2/src/lib.rs:14:42
   |
14 | #![cfg_attr(feature = "nightly", feature(llvm_asm))]
   |                                          ^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0635`.
error: could not compile `parking_lot` due to 3 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

Ouput of `rustup show`:

```
rustup home:  /home/riley/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
1.48.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (directory override for '/home/riley/projects/rust-fractal-gui')
rustc 1.64.0-nightly (c2f428d2f 2022-07-14)
```

I have updated my nightly toolchain to the latest version with `rustup update nightly` and then `rustup override set nightly` [see this issue](https://github.com/Amanieu/parking_lot/issues/225) but it did not take care of the problem.

Comment: what about if you run `rustup override set nightly` then try building again? it looks like you *updated* nightly, but didn't actually specify to Cargo to use it

Comment: @JeremyMeadows, that didn't make a difference. I edited my question to include that.

Comment: hmm, I might be able to try to build it when I get on my personal machine and see what happens

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/70173) after doing some hunting around

Comment: It seems that the `asm!` macro was renamed to `llvm_asm!` and then deprecated in favor of a new `asm!` macro (see [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/68404) issue), maybe `llvm_asm!` has been removed in the most recent rustc.

Comment: Glad you found the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `rustc-nightly-2022-01-17` the macro `llvm_asm!` was removed in favor of the new `asm!` macro. `rust-fractal-gui` was using an outdated version of `parking_lot` which still used the `llvm_asm!` macro, causing this error. A [PR](https://github.com/rust-fractal/rust-fractal-gui/pull/3) has since been merged which fixes the issue.